# How to redirect URL:PORT traffic to multiple external IP:Port?

Tags: networking, server, iptables, routing

Currently, I'm using iptables to redirect incoming requests for "website.com:27015" to "xx.xx.xx.xx:27015". Problem is, since iptables redirects via the port 27015, I can only redirect to one single location.

But since I want to expand the number of locations I can reroute to, I'm searching for a method to reroute via the URL+PORT now.

Example:

```
dm.website.com:27015 reroutes to yy.yy.yy.yy:27020
private.website.com:27015 reroutes to xx.xx.xx.xx:27015

(same url, different subdomains)
etc..
```

Any suggestions/solutions for this problem are greatly appreciated! ^^

Edit: Need to listen for UDP connections as well as TCP

Comment: Then why would you tag `nginx`?

Comment: I was not aware that it was TCP only.

Comment: I think clarifying the reason why you want to do this would help suggest an appropriate solution to your task. Is it for redundancy, high-availability, etc.? Perhaps a reverse proxy webserver would be better suited for the task?

Answer (score 0):

"If all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail..."

You need [DNS redirection](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-01031/0/An-Overview-of-BIND-9-Documentation.html) ;-)